# Reduce to sum of products

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm given the equation
$F = (x+w)z' + x(y+z) + xz$

The inverse I got is
$F' = [(x'+z)*(w'+z)]*[(x'+y')*(x'+z')]*[x'+z']$

To start I would expand 
$F'= [x'w' + x'z + zw'+zz] * [x'x' + x'z' + y'x' + y'z'] * [x'+z']$

What laws can I apply here to simplify further then keep distributing out?

I'm having trouble expanding this further. What would the next expression be?

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  Is your question about how to get $F$ as the SOP or how to get $F'$ as the SOP?  I think you mean the second, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the $(x'y')$ term in $F'$ read $(x' + y')$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it's much easier to invert an expression once it's in POS or SOP form.  So, I'll begin by getting $F$ as the product of sums, then invert.  We have:
$$
\begin{align}
F &= (x+w)z'+x(y+z)+\{x(z)\} \text{  ......................factor out the $x$}\\
  &= (x+w)z'+x(y+z+\{z\}) \text{ ...........................expand $ab+cd=(a+c)(a+d)(b+c)(b+d)$}\\
  &= (x+w+x)(x+w+y+z)(z'+x)(z'+y+z) \text{  ...remove redundant terms}\\
  &= (w+x)(x+z')
\end{align}
$$
To invert, apply deMorgan's law:
$$
\begin{align}
F' &= w'x'+x'z\\
   &= (w'x'y'z'+w'x'y'z+w'x'yz'+w'x'yz)\\
   &\,\,+ (w'x'y'z+w'x'yz+wx'y'z+wx'yz)\\
   &= 
\end{align}
$$

---

Inverting first you get this:

$$
\begin{align}
F'&=[(x+w)z'+x(y+z)+xz]'\\
  &=[(x+w)z']'[x(y+z)]'[xz]'\\
  &=[x'w'+z][x'+y'z'][x'+z']\\
\end{align}
$$
Now, expand that product of binomials
$$
\begin{align}
F'&=[w'x'+z][x'+y'z'][x'+z']\\
  &=w'x'+(w'x'z')+w'x'y'z'+(x'w'y'z')+(\text{stuff containing $zz'$})+x'z\\
  &=w'x'+x'z
\end{align}
$$
From there, expand each sum to get the SOP form as above

---

Okay so maybe I'll correct all that, but the quickest way to do SOP is just with a truth table.  This is the truth table for $F'$:
[image: Truth table]

Reading down the list, we note that rows 0,1,2,3,6, and 7 have $1$s.  So,
$$
F'=m_0+m_1+m_2+m_3+m_6+m_7
$$

Comment: I'm confused on your removed redundant terms. at that point I have (x+w+x)(x+w+y+z+z)(z'+x)(x'+y+z+z). So I'm removing the x in the first term, z in the second, and z in the third to get (z+w)(x+w+y+z)(z'+x)(z'+y+z) right? What did I miss there?

Comment: Made a mistake there: $(w+x)(w+x+y+z)=(w+x)$, I did the reverse.  The other reduction I made is that $$(z+y+z')=(y+(z+z'))=y+1=1$$

Comment: Is it possible you could supply the answer by finding the inverse first then the sum of products for that inverse? I know its the same as you have above but I'm having more trouble that way. :(

Comment: All right, I'll write it up that way. Apparently, I was having trouble that way too :P. Are you supposed to do it algebraically, or can you just do it with a truth table?

Comment: Algebraically. With a truth table it might be huge since there are four variables.

Comment: It is surprisingly effective for this stuff.  Remember that each 1 on the truth table corresponds to a term in the SOP form

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9432/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-user1766888)